# Private set, and get returns null/empty?

Tags: c#

I cant retrieve the result of `ReturnName`

```
//
private string testName;
public string ReturnName
{
    private set { testName = "MyName"; }
    get { return testName; }
}

//
string i = data.ReturnName;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just do this:

```
public string ReturnName
{
    get { return "MyName"; }
}

//
string i = data.ReturnName;
```

You do not need the set if you are just returning a hard coded value. More to your point, the reason you are getting the error is because you probably never call set. If you want a default value, then you should do something more like this:

```
private string testName = "MyName";
public string ReturnName
{
    private set { testName = value; }
    get { return testName; }
}

//
string i = data.ReturnName;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code never sets `ReturnName`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are calling from the other class, `ReturnName` is always empty since you cannot set a value from it. The only time it will return `MyName` is when you are setting any value on the property on the same class but the value will be returned is `MyName`.

Consider the following example,

```
public Class SampleClass
(
    private string testName;
    public string ReturnName
    {
        private set { testName = "MyName"; }
        get { return testName; }
    }

    public void MethodName()
    {
        ReturnName = "hello";
        Console.WriteLine(ReturnName);
    }
)

public class Main
{
    SampleClass _x = new SampleClass();
    Console.WriteLine(_x.ReturnName);     // will output EMPTY
    _x.MethodName();                      // will output MyName
}
```